# C# facebook graph / How to upload an image on Facebook album?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload an image using ASP.NET with C#.I do not how to send image in parameter 
source="F://sample.jpg".I have also tried  to send an image in a byte format.

> URL is
>   http://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos?access_token=access_tokenvalue;

Post Data is

> source= "F://sample.jpg"

I am getting an exception.Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the error message you're getting?  Might be helpful in tracking down exactly what the error is.  In any case, I'm not too familiar with the Facebook APIs but it appears in the Graph API document for [Photo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo) that you have to prefix the file path with an @.

```
source="@F:\\sample.jpg"
```